Why is the Postgres query planner choosing the wrong strategy?
I have a Postgres/Postgis table with ~50M rows. I am making requests similar to this:
select * from building b  where ST_Intersects(b.point, some_fixed_geometry)
order by id limit 20 offset X;

The table has a geometric index for the column point and also an index on the column id.
Here is my issue: when the offset X is "big enough", the query planner chosen strategy is the following:
QUERY PLAN                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
Limit  (cost=498976.72..498979.05 rows=20 width=688) (actual time=325.808..365.555 rows=20 loops=1)                                                                                                                                                            |
  ->  Gather Merge  (cost=497809.97..501989.96 rows=35826 width=688) (actual time=310.281..353.950 rows=10020 loops=1)                                                                                                                                         |
        Workers Planned: 2                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     |
        Workers Launched: 2                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    |
        ->  Sort  (cost=496809.95..496854.73 rows=17913 width=688) (actual time=241.005..241.571 rows=3391 loops=3)                                                                                                                                            |
              Sort Key: id                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     |
              Sort Method: top-N heapsort  Memory: 14533kB                                                                                                                                                                                                     |
              Worker 0:  Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 13821kB                                                                                                                                                                                               |
              Worker 1:  Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 14815kB                                                                                                                                                                                               |
              ->  Parallel Bitmap Heap Scan on batid_building bb  (cost=858.30..495544.51 rows=17913 width=688) (actual time=20.381..218.943 rows=16302 loops=3)                                                                                               |
                    Filter: st_intersects(point, '0103000020E6100000010000001100000000363CD6E26A1340DC518FC6F1E24640A0D5E1400B561340A4F3FED5E4E34640A0CE32DB35471340D8A4F9BA06E34640A0392821F647134010800C8E3DE2464040DE064C6A53134060F7990357E14640C0AD4272154|
                    Rows Removed by Filter: 4063                                                                                                                                                                                                               |
                    Heap Blocks: exact=27340                                                                                                                                                                                                                   |
                    ->  Bitmap Index Scan on batid_building_point_c8b72b20_id  (cost=0.00..847.55 rows=42991 width=0) (actual time=31.404..31.405 rows=61095 loops=1)                                                                                          |
                          Index Cond: (point && '0103000020E6100000010000001100000000363CD6E26A1340DC518FC6F1E24640A0D5E1400B561340A4F3FED5E4E34640A0CE32DB35471340D8A4F9BA06E34640A0392821F647134010800C8E3DE2464040DE064C6A53134060F7990357E14640C0AD42721546|
Planning Time: 1.336 ms                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        |
JIT:                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           |
  Functions: 14                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                |
  Options: Inlining false, Optimization false, Expressions true, Deforming true                                                                                                                                                                                |
  Timing: Generation 3.973 ms, Inlining 0.000 ms, Optimization 2.246 ms, Emission 24.984 ms, Total 31.202 ms                                                                                                                                                   |
Execution Time: 370.101 ms                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     |

First the geometric index is used to get the buildings inside the given geometry, then a sort is performed for the order by. This is very efficient, the query takes 370ms.
If the offset is small, for example 0, then the following strategy is used:
QUERY PLAN                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
Limit  (cost=1000.59..254817.72 rows=20 width=688) (actual time=491460.299..492613.979 rows=20 loops=1)                                                                                                                                                        |
  ->  Gather Merge  (cost=1000.59..545593622.28 rows=42991 width=688) (actual time=491446.901..492600.559 rows=20 loops=1)                                                                                                                                     |
        Workers Planned: 2                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     |
        Workers Launched: 2                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    |
        ->  Parallel Index Scan using batid_building_pkey on batid_building bb  (cost=0.56..545587660.03 rows=17913 width=688) (actual time=491279.824..492142.885 rows=10 loops=3)                                                                            |
              Filter: st_intersects(point, '0103000020E6100000010000001100000000363CD6E26A1340DC518FC6F1E24640A0D5E1400B561340A4F3FED5E4E34640A0CE32DB35471340D8A4F9BA06E34640A0392821F647134010800C8E3DE2464040DE064C6A53134060F7990357E14640C0AD4272154613401|
              Rows Removed by Filter: 3928803                                                                                                                                                                                                                  |
Planning Time: 1.523 ms                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        |
JIT:                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           |
  Functions: 14                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                |
  Options: Inlining false, Optimization false, Expressions true, Deforming true                                                                                                                                                                                |
  Timing: Generation 4.062 ms, Inlining 0.000 ms, Optimization 2.325 ms, Emission 26.937 ms, Total 33.324 ms                                                                                                                                                   |
Execution Time: 492619.363 ms                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  |

The index on the column id is scanned and each row is checked against the geometric condition. This is very inefficient, the query takes 492sec.
It seems to me that if the first approach can return 20 results with an offset of 10000, it could also return very efficiently 20 results with any smaller offset.
My questions are: why is the first approach not prefered for all values of offsets? What can I do the point the DB in the right direction?
My hypothesis are:

the query planner underestimates in strategy 2 the number of buildings it needs to scan before finding 20 buildings inside the given geometry. So it uses the index on the id column and verify the geometric condition on a huge number of buildings.

the query planner overestimates in strategy 1 the cost of the Parallel Bitmap Heap Scan


The table has been vaccumed and analyzed.


the query planner underestimates in strategy 2 the number of buildings it needs to scan before finding 20 buildings inside the given geometry.

Based on the ratio of the costs, it thinks it will need to scan about 254817.72/545593622.28, or 1/2140, of the table to find the 10 rows to keep.
But instead it had to scan 3928803/~50M or about 1/12 of it.  So yes, that estimate is off by over 150 fold, because things matching the geometry are preferentially at the high end of the id range, not the low end.
Alas, there is little you can do about this estimation problem.  You could force the planners hand by writing ORDER BY id+0 LIMIT...

Your first hypothesis is correct. The estimates don't seem to be off, so I guess it is bad luck that all the matching buildings have a high id. ORDER BY id DESC might happen to be faster, but that would just be luck and won't work for different geometries.

Since LIMIT+OFFSET is usually used for pagination, here's a faster solution for both cases:
Do the whole search for "some_fixed_geometry" and store the results in a cache table. You don't need to store the whole rows, only the primary key and maybe some other fields you'd need to refine search, if any. You should add a LIMIT which should be quite high, maybe a few thousands, to avoid fetching an unreasonably high number of rows in case the search criteria is not selective.
Then, instead of re-doing the whole query with LIMIT+OFFSET, when you need results from the next page, fetch them from the cache table. This will make displaying the next pages much faster.
This requires a bit of logistics: assign a search_id to each search query, periodically purge the cache of old entries, etc.
If you add a "row number" column, and an index on (search_id,row_number) you can get any chunk of the results without doing a sort or skipping rows, making pagination much faster.
Instead of a cache table, you can also retrieve the whole results of the search query and store them in the application, making the cache local to the application. If the rows are large, you can also retrieve just the ids.
